# Running kubectl command from jenkins container

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, kubectl, minikube

I installed minikube on a VirtualBox(ubuntu) to simulate a deploy environment and used Jenkins pipeline.
On my jenkins container i also installed kubectl command to control minikube.

So i create the following stage:

```
stage("k8s command test") {                        
        withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'cbcba826-ef01-4b18-856f-e6dc4eb27c1f', usernameVariable: 'my-user', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]) {
            sh """
                kubectl config view
                kubectl create -f /home/my-user/file-svc.yml
            """
        }
    }
```

First thing my cluster seems to be empty in output i have :

```
+ kubectl config view
apiVersion: v1
clusters: []
contexts: []
current-context: ""
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users: []
```

if i check .kube/config i have the following config :

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /home/my-user/.minikube/ca.crt
    server: https://127.0.0.1:8443
  name: minikube
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: minikube
    user: minikube
  name: minikube
current-context: minikube
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: minikube
  user:
    as-user-extra: {}
    client-certificate: /home/my-user/.minikube/client.crt
    client-key: /home/my-user/.minikube/client.key
```

As i'm new on kubernetes i need help to understand how to make possible the communication between jenkins and minikube.

consequently kubectl create -f /home/my-user/file-svc.yml raised an error about authentication.
I read many article kubectl need certificate to be connected to the API server how can i do that in jenkins

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thank for your help, finaly i set cluster on jenkins and use --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true to avoid authentication as it's a test machine

```
kubectl config set-cluster minikube --server=https://127.0.0.1:8443 --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true
kubectl config set-context minikube --cluster=minikube --user=minikube
kubectl config use-context minikube
```

And both container start on the same network

Answer (score 5):

It seems KUBECONFIG environment variable is not assigned to the correct config file.Therefore, you need to assign it first by following the command

```
export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config
```

Now kubectl can communicate with kube-api server. However, It needs to show its identity and capability to take actions on k8s resources, therefore, it will take client.crt and client.key files whenever it communicate with kube-api server. 
Now it can perform following tasks

```
kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
kubectl get pods
kubectl get nodes
```

**Solutions to your problem**

Jenkins needs to have these certificate and keys in order to perform operations such as create, apply, get ,watch etc.

Comment: Thank for your help,